# Some Frames in Listview have sharp edges and some are round (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Some Frames in Listview have sharp edges and some are round (Xamarin forms)

I have a Xamarin forms app with a list view. The horizontal row has a couple different frames (boxes with text).

The issue is some of the frames have sharp edges and others are rounded. I can't see any pattern (size of text, etc).

I tried updating the padding but it did not have any effect on this issue.

What could cause the border/edges to be different?
How can I explicitly set them?

I am testing in the Android Simulator at the moment if it matters.

Comment: a screenshot illustrating the issue would be really helpful

Comment: maybe if you show us a part of your code we could understand it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your box views within a frame so that all the boxviews will have the rounded corners.

```
  <Frame OutlineColor="Black" HasShadow="False" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BoxView x:Name="boxViewSeparator" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="10000" BackgroundColor="Green" />
  </Frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the listview around some.
I would like to explicitly set this property (borders).

Example of straight edges

[image: Straight edges]

Straight and round
[image: Straight and round]
Round in the middle
[image]